# how to check all editText (empty or not) for answer that I put in list

Tags: android

I need help to check all editText that I use to answer my question if is it empty or not. I put all the answer in list. so i can send all my answers  when I click the submit button at the end of question. but I got confused how to check all edittext that I have.   
the edittext will appear according the total of the questions. 
example: i have 5 questions,and i show the question 1 page 1 question. when i click next button, the next page will show question number two with blank edittext. it is like that until the question is done. what i want is, when i click send/ok, it will check all edittext I really need help, please help me.. thank you

```
String[] answerCollection;
String[] questionCollection;
private int questionPos = 0;
private EditText jawaban;

final Button kirim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kirim);
                kirim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(v == kirim){
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(TugasSoal.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Apakah Anda yakin akan mengirim jawaban Anda? Anda tidak dapat mengakses kembali tugas yang sudah dikirim");
                            builder.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
    
                            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                        // do something after confirm
                                    
                                    String finalAnswer = "";
                                    answerCollection[questionPos] = jawaban.getText().toString();
                                    
                                    for(int i = 0;i <answerCollection.length;i++){
                                        finalAnswer += (i+1) + "." + answerCollection[i] + "\n\n"; 
                                    }
                                    
                                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jawab", finalAnswer));
    
                                    
                                    String response = null;
    
                                    try {
                                        linkurl = new Koneksi(TugasSoal.this);
                                        SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
                                        SERVER_URL += "/mobile/tugasKirimTeks.php?idtgs="+param2+"&idu="+param3;
                                       response = CourseHttpClient.executeHttpPost(SERVER_URL, postParameters);
    
                                       String res = response.toString();
    
                                       res = res.trim();
    
                                       res = res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                                       if(res.equals("1")){
                                           createDialog("Selamat", "Jawaban Anda Berhasil Dikirim");
                                           finish();
                                       }else
                                       {
                                           createDialog("Maaf", "Jawaban Anda Gagal Terkirim");
                                       }
                                    }
    
                                    catch (Exception e) {
    
                                       jawaban.setText(e.toString());
    
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }); 
    
                            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            }); 
    
                            builder.create().show();    
                        }
                     }
                });
```

next and prevpart

```
prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    answerCollection[questionPos] = jawaban.getText().toString();
                    
                    if(questionPos > 0){
                        questionPos -=1;
                        RefreshQuestionandAnswer();
//                      next.setEnabled(true);
//                      if(questionPos == 0)
//                          back.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });
            
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    answerCollection[questionPos] = jawaban.getText().toString();
                    
                    if(questionPos < questionCollection.length - 1) {
                        questionPos +=1;
                        RefreshQuestionandAnswer();
//                      prev.setEnabled(true);
//                      if(questionPos == questionCollection.length - 1)
//                          next.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

show the question part

```
linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
            SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
            SERVER_URL += "/mobile/TugasSoal.php?idc="+param1+"&ida="+param2+"&idu="+param3;

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
            
            //parameter
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();{
            try {
               //add parameter
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
               
              HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
              HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();
              
              //read content
              InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
              BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
              
              String content = "";
              String line = "";

              while((line = read.readLine())!=null){
                 content += line;
              }
              
              Log.d("ADBUG", "content: "+content);
              
              
              //json
              if(!content.equals("null")){
              
                 try {
                    JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(content);
                    String namaTugas="";
                    String detailTugas="";

                    JSONObject jsonObj = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
                    namaTugas = jsonObj.getString("name");
                    detailTugas = jsonObj.getString("description");
                    
                    questionCollection = detailTugas.split("\n");
                    answerCollection = new String[questionCollection.length];
                    judulTugas.setText(namaTugas);
                    
                    RefreshQuestionandAnswer();
                   
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 
              }else{
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
              
           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
       
            }
            
        }
        
        private void RefreshQuestionandAnswer()
        {
            jawaban.setText(answerCollection[questionPos]);
            isiTugas.setText(questionCollection[questionPos]);
        }
```

when I first open the menu for answer the question
[image: when I first open the menu for answer the question]

[image]

after i click next button

Comment: how to check meaning?.

Comment: @Raghunandan , oops sorry.. I'm forgot to put if edittext is empty or not...

Comment: I don't understand... how many EditText objects do you have? what do you want to do with them?

Comment: `if(editText.getText().equalsignorecase(null))` or `editText.getText().equals(null)`

Comment: @dors, the edittext will appear according the total of the questions. example: i have 5 questions,and i show the question 1 page 1 question. when i click next button, the next page will show question number two with blank edittext. it is like that until the question is done. what i want is, when i click send/ok, it will check all edittext. thank you

Comment: @Raghunandan, it will only check one my edittext. what i want is how to check all.. i put the example at the comment above. thank you

Comment: @Raghunandan, i can't do that. because the edittext appear according the total of the questions. thank you

Comment: When you say "when i click next button, the next page..." do you mean that you start a new activity, or just replace the content of your current Activity's TextViews and EditText?

Comment: @blackneko how to initialize your edittext objects

Comment: @dors, i think not replace , because i made it when i click back button the answer for first question or the question before still in there. so i think it start new activity.

Comment: @dors, can you help me? how to check all the answer field? thank you very much...

Comment: @Raghunandan, I updated the codes. for that part too. thank you

Comment: @blackneko As I understand: You got 5 questions, they are asked separately, so you can't do an all in one check. But why don't you check if EditText is empty everytime he goes to the next question?

Comment: @Bigflow, 5 questions just example.. the questions can more than 5 or less, depend on the teacher make it.. so i make it like that, when the student click the next button the student will have the question and blank edittext. but when the student click prev button, it will go to prev question and the answer for prev question still in there.. and i wanna check all the edittext when i click the button for send. thank you very much for your respond...

Comment: @blackneko 1 step at a time. I made an answer for the "show previous answer of question" part first. First try this to get to work, then we go further to the checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "Show answer of previous question" part:
I would make an ArrayList something like:

```
    List answerList = new ArrayList(); 


    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        answerCollection[questionPos] = jawaban.getText().toString();

                        if(questionPos < questionCollection.length - 1) {
                            if (answerCollection.get(questionPos).toString().equals("")){
                                answerList.add(questionPos, "0");//You check if the user has enetered an answer, if yes, it put a 1 into the array, if not, a 0
                            } else {
                                answerList.add(questionPos, "1");
                            }
                            questionPos +=1;
                            RefreshQuestionandAnswer();
    //                      prev.setEnabled(true);
    //                      if(questionPos == questionCollection.length - 1)
    //                      next.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Then at the send button, check the Arraylist on zero's.

```
for (int i = 0; i < answerList.size(); i++){
    if (answerList.get(i).toString().equals("0")){
        //no answer is given to question number i      
    }
}
```

Something like this

Comment: ehhm... the answer show for prev and next button already works fine.. but what i need is how to check all the edittext when i click OK button in confirmation .. when I click the OK button the data will send to the database. but I want to check it first, is there any edittext empty or not.. thank you very much

Comment: @blackneko Oh, So many comments I was little confused I guess ;p.
But the check, you could also use an ArrayList. A little different, will edit answer, let you know when it is ready.

Comment: hahaha it's okay... :) ... okay Bigflow, really thank you very much :D

Comment: @blackneko Maybe not everything on the good place, but I hope you get an idea of it :) (I comment sometimes behind a code what I do/mean with it)

Comment: Bigflow, is there any other way.. because i think I already put the answer in array? O.o when i put that code on my next button , I got warning.. O.o thank you

Comment: **change** `if (answerCollection.get(questionPos).equals("")){`
**to**
 `if (answerCollection.get(questionPos).toString().equals("")){`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32807/discussion-between-bigflow-and-blackneko)

Comment: Bigflow, I pass my final presentation!!! it success!!! my teachers forget about that box thing hahaha.. thank you very much for ur support and help :D

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

I would keep and ArrayList of the user's answers (at index 0, there will be answer1, and index n will be answer (n-1)).

I would also keep a "currentQuestionIndex" int member to indicate the question I am currently showing (starts at 0)

Every time the user clicks the button, I would save that answer in the ArrayList.

```
answersArrayList.add(myEditText.getText().toString());
```

I would NOT start a new activity when a new question needs to be presented.

Handling the "back" key:

You can override the onBackPressed() method, and use the currentQuestionIndex member to decide if to show a previous question, or to exit the activity.

But I find that annoying (if I am at question 5, I need to press back 5 times!).
What I would do is add a "next question" and "prev question" buttons to navigate through questions, and when pressing back I would show a dialog asking if the user wants to exit

Comment: back button id mean previous button not back to exit.. hehe.. for the xml back button = prev button for look the prev question.. hehe. do you mean like i did in my next code and prev code above? and how to check if one or more edititext is empty when i click send? thank you very much

Comment: Can you please upload a picture of your UI so I will understand your problem better?

Comment: You should only have 1 EditText. when you click on "send" you should take the answers from the ArrayList I talked about

Comment: yes, I only have 1 edittext.. i declare it in the first part my code `private EditText jawaban;` and i put the answers in string array.. but i hv no idea how to check it all.. O.o thank you

Comment: What do you mean when you say "check"?

Comment: check, is there any edittext still empty or not.. if there is still one or more edittext that still empty the data can't be send..

Comment: what i want is, when the user click OK button in confirmation dialog(like in my code) then there is any checking codes for check if the edittext already fill all or not.. if there is still any editttext tat empty than the data can't be send, and will appear alert dialog... thank you

Comment: Do this check before allowing the user to continue:
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(myEditText.getText().toString())){
//show error to user and don't allow him to continue
}

Comment: so before the user click next? O.o

Comment: thank you very much to give this idea!!! really works.. thank you very much dors :D